# Hide duplicate items from array (not delete)

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to do?

For example:

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Need to hide like this: `[1, 2, ***3, 3, 3*** 3]`

For elements with *** - `.style.visibility = "hidden"`

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Hide from what? Are you creating HTML? Or what do you mean by "hide"? You can use a filter

Comment: Do the elements in your array represent some DOM elements somehow?

Comment: @Alex I get them through api, putting them in an array.

Comment: What is the relation between `array` element and `css`

Comment: @Mina I need to display these elements on the page. But repetitive hide. (not delete)

Comment: The elements of a JavaScript array don't have a css style, you need to show us how you are currently turning this array into HTML that css can be applied to.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "hide" array elements from JS.

You can create a NEW array without the dupes or filter on accessing the array.

So for example use a Set

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3];
const dedup = [...new Set(arr)];

console.log(dedup)

// here we render all hidden

container.innerHTML = arr.map(item => `<span data-id="${item}" hidden>${item}</span>`).join("")

// and show the first unique 

dedup.forEach(unique => document.querySelector(`[data-id="${unique}"]`).hidden = false)
```

```css
#container span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```